# HTML 5 dataset issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

Can anyone tell me why the following line of code throws and error

```
$('#id').dataset.assoc
```

and these two do not?

```
$('#id').data("assoc")
$('#id').dataset.file_id
```

Is it something to do with the word assoc?

Comment: maybe because thats not how it works?

Comment: [**Learn jQuery**](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: First of all, *what does the error say?* Secondly, what's the relation supposed to be between the three lines? The first is accessing an object property, the second is calling a function and in the third it's a completely different property (`dataset` not `data`).

Comment: In addition to the [Jquery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), you likely would want to check out the [HTML5 custom data-* tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: I'm suprised if the last one actually works ?

Comment: @adeneo could be similar value coincidence

Comment: I could be mistaken, but the last one is equivalent to `document.getElementById("id").getAttribute("data-file_id");`

Comment: No it's not? I searched the source, and couldn't find a `$().dataset`, and in a fiddle test, it comes back as `undefined`, so it shouldn't work.

Comment: The last one is to show you it does work when I ask for "file_id" also several others work fine.. It's just the "assoc" that returns undefined.

Comment: Then it's a fluke, the last one shouldn't work.

Comment: my money on a custom plugin that adds a `dataset` attribute, and while it contains `file_id`,  it simply doesnt contain `assoc`

Comment: or maybe op is confusing jquery with vanilla js, try taking the plain element out of the jquery object first `$('#id')[0].dataset.assoc` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/aq1hk153/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by adeneo and Banana, the first and the last should not work. Attempted both in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7pq357b/1/) and both threw errors. This is because `.dataset` is not within jQuery. You must have code internally or externally adding dataset to that jQuery object.

the following are similar syntax but should work (where with only the details you gave, your code shouldn't work):

```
document.getElementById("id").dataset.assoc
$("#id")[0].dataset.assoc
```

This is due to [data-* attributes in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: I am not sure why some of my data names work and others don't perhaps you are correct and there is code extending it somewhere. Either way I was hoping to get a better understanding of this and I appreciate you taking the time to clarify.

Comment: You're welcome, I also updated the fiddle to show .dataset grabbing data-* values (previously it showed undefined, because they were never actually set). If you look into it more and find the source of the issue I wouldn't mind hearing what exactly was causing the issue. Good luck!